# Sorting one array by another in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file with 200000 lines,the third column is velocity which should be sorted.I am just giving first 20 lines

```
second.txt

0 0 1.200000
0 1 1.200000
0 2 1.200000
0 3 1.200000
0 4 1.200000
0 5 1.200000
0 6 1.200000
0 7 1.200000
0 8 1.200000
0 9 1.200000
0 10 1.200000
0 11 1.200000
0 12 1.200000
0 13 1.200000
0 14 1.200000
0 15 1.200000
0 16 1.200000
0 17 1.200000
0 18 1.200000
0 19 1.200000
```

Array which should be used as a reference

```
newindex1.txt 

0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
14 0
15 0
16 0
17 0
18 0
19 0
```

What I want is to take third column value and place it to appropriate `newindex1.txt` index pair.

Desired output

```
    0 0 1.200000
    1 0 1.200000
    2 0 1.200000
    3 0 1.200000
    4 0 1.200000
    5 0 1.200000
    6 0 1.200000
    7 0 1.200000
    8 0 1.200000
    9 0 1.200000
    10 0 1.200000
    11 0 1.200000
    12 0 1.200000
    13 0 1.200000
    14 0 1.200000
    15 0 1.200000
    16 0 1.200000
    17 0 1.200000
    18 0 1.200000
    19 0 1.200000
```

All examples are just 20 lines,real files are huge.

I have tried this

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from operator import itemgetter

s = loadtxt("second.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
ni = loadtxt("newindex1.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)

for i, l in enumerate(ni):
    for m,n,v in s:
        s[m,n,v] == ni[i,l]
```

It does not work

```
    s[m,n,v] == ni[i,l]
IndexError: too many indices
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `s` is only 2 dimensional, but you're trying to index it with 3 indices (`m`,`n`,`v`).  What are you trying to do in the last line?   Not to mention the fact that the way you are looping, `m`,`n`, and `v` are the *entries* in `s`, none of them are indices (same goes for `l`).  The only index in all of your code is `i`.

Comment: @Racialz Take a look at edited output,pls!

Comment: @brettb How to solve this?I want to extract value from one array and allocate it to proper index of the second.I have showed the desired output.

Comment: The problem is still underspecified.  What you initially say you want to do and later say are different.  Here is the key question: can some kind of sort of `second.txt` give you what you want (without any reference to another file), or is it necessary to base the output on another file (in this case, `newindex1.txt`)?

Comment: @Alan It is necessay,think of these two columns as mesh coordinates in 2d!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `newindex1.txt` is sorted by an unknown rule, I think you might use a dict to get a velocity by an index ():

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from operator import itemgetter

s = loadtxt("second.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)
ni = loadtxt("newindex1.txt", delimiter=" ", unpack=False)

index = {}

for m,n,v in s:
    index [(m,n)] = v

for i,l in ni:
    key = (i,l)

    if key in index.keys ():
        print (i, l, index [key])
```

Comment: Try to use pairs instead of string keys. See updated code above.